# how to get the toltal number of rows in dojogrid table in selenium webdriver?

Tags: testng

how to get the total number of rows in dojogrid table in selenium webdriver?
please give me a method to find out in selenium webdriver.
gridtable doestnt consist of dynamic xpath and doesnt contain id .

Thanks in advance

Comment: it consist of below info <div class="dojoxGridScrollbox" wairole="presentation
dojoattachpoint="scrollboxNode" role="presentation" style="height: 423px;">

Comment: Can you please post html source code for this.?

Comment: tell me to find number of rows in table in testng .<div id="dojox_grid__View_17" class="dojoxGridView" wairole="presentation" role="presentation" widgetid="dojox_grid__View_17" style="width: 1108px; height: 423px; left: 1px; top: 0px;">
<input class="dojoxGridHiddenFocus" type="checkbox" wairole="presentation" dojoattachpoint="hiddenFocusNode" role="presentation">
<input class="dojoxGridHiddenFocus" type="checkbox" wairole="presentation" role="presentation">    @Anil

Comment: @ Anil....this id changes dynamically

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("\\div[contains(@class,'dojoxGridView')\\input"));
    int count=list.size();
```

I am expecting, this will work. If doesn't, you need to provide me some more details on this.

Comment: thanks @ anil.i hav one more query , i need to call this list from another class.i cant use driver.findelement in framework of selenium.please tell me that, how to create this list in one method and i have to call that method into main class.locators will be in one class. for example..  GenericKeywords.rightclickOn(Security_OR.click_SecurityPage_Groups); generickeywords class consist of rightclickon method,Security_OR is also a class consist of variable(loacator such as xpath, id) .like wise i have to change this.please help me.thanks in advance

Comment: So, can we use driver.findelement in GenericKeywords  class?
or there is one more layer of code below this?